# Why does the Delphi compiler allow a comma after the final parameter in a method call?

Tags: delphi, compiler-construction, history

Say I had a function such as this one

```
procedure TMyObject.DoSomething(text: string);
begin
    // do something important with the text
end;
```

When I call the method like so

```
DoSomething('some text', );
```

the code editor displays a red squiggly at the comma after the last parameter, just as I would have expected. The compiler, however, accepts this code and everything works as if the comma wasn't there.

Why does this appear to be legal syntax? Is there some historical reason this is still supported today (I have tried this in Delphi 2006 and [others](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/alt.comp.lang.borland-delphi/2008-09/msg00041.html) seemed to have experienced it in 2007 as well)?

Comment: IIRC, I have seen a similar bug sometime, when a missing closing parenthesis `)` was omitted by mistake, and the code still would compile.

Comment: what versions accept this? Definitely a parser bug, albeit a harmless one.

Comment: @WarrenP As it says in the question: I have tried this in Delphi 2006 and [others](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Delphi/alt.comp.lang.borland-delphi/2008-09/msg00041.html) seem to have experienced it in 2007 as well. It is harmless, indeed, I just came across a method call that by accident was using this syntax and asked myself why it had ever compiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That codes results in a compile error (E2034 Too many actual parameters) in Delphi 6, 2010 and XE2. I guess it's a compiler bug in your version since it is not legal syntax.

Comment: The same thing happens in Delphi 4 and Delphi 2009.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You mean it's a compile error in those versions? Looks like quite a local bug.

Comment: @TLama Yes, that's what Andreas means, that in D4 and 2009, the code is a compile error. So far we know that it is compile error in D6 and D2009, but not in D2006.